# When installing Maven via MacPorts what does the final command "sudo maven_select maven3" do?

Tags: maven, macports

When installing Maven via MacPorts when it completes it prints the command

```
To fully complete your installation and make maven 3.0.3 the default, please run

sudo maven_select maven3
```

What does this final command do when you run it? 
The output it produces is

```
--->  Cleaning maven3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to have a dirty Maven.... Terrible stuff happens when you do... :)

The command will just remove the old files that are no longer needed and make maven3 the default for the system. Presumably it'll just be setting symbolic links

Comment: So are you saying that the command sudo maven_select maven3 just removes an older Maven version if it exists?

Comment: no, it'll just set the version 3 as the default, you'll have to remove old versions manually